# Place footnotes only at end of flextable table over multiple pages, pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown, flextable

I am creating a pdf document with `bookdown` using tables made with `flextable`. I have a long footnote for a number of the tables, which spread over multiple pages.

Is it possible to set the footnote to only appear at the bottom, not on every page?

This is an example with iris: the footnote is on everypage

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r table}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

flextable(iris)%>%
  add_footer_lines("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
```
````